# Spree commerce - Edit User object properties

Tags: ruby-on-rails, class, spree, preference

I'm new to spree and also still learning Rails

I don't completely understand how can I add new properties to the Spree::User object, so that I can set more data to the users that are registering to my site.

According to the not-so-clear documentation, I understand that I should create a User class and add preferences:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  preference :hot_salsa, :boolean
  preference :dark_chocolate, :boolean, :default => true
  preference :color, :string
  preference :favorite_number, :integer
  preference :language, :string, :default => "English"
end
```

But I'm not sure where should I save this file or how to name it at all.

Am I on the correct path?

Comment: IMHO This part is well documented. https://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/logic.html#extending-classes
You create migraton, eval class and change or extend views as in link mention by @Saurabh

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using a decorator. You can create the decorator as `app/models/spree/user_decorator.rb` and add your code in it.

```
Spree::User.class_eval do
  preference :hot_salsa, :boolean
  preference :dark_chocolate, :boolean, :default => true
  preference :color, :string
  preference :favorite_number, :integer
  preference :language, :string, :default => "English"
end
```

Find documentation for overidding or extending code [here](https://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/deface_overrides_tutorial.html).

Answer (score 1):

The fields you are adding should not be used as preferences as the value for preferences are serialised and then stored which will not be useful if you want to do some filtering/querying on these fields.

Rather these should be

- separate attributes of user model (columns of `spree_users` table).
- attributes of a separate new table may be `spree_user_details` (`belongs_to :user`) with has_one association from user model.